# Function of a past participle in a German sentence

Tags: grammar-identification, passive, past-participle

**Note for understanding of existing answers**

The title of this question read formerly: *Etymology of past participle functioning as noun*.

---

I am reading a German mathematics handout. In it, the following sentence is given in one of the sections:

> Gesucht ist eine "Liste" aller Loesungen (x,y,z)

I don't understand the role of Gesucht in the above sentence. What exactly is the type and mechanics of construction used ?

Comment: It's not a noun. It's just capitalized because it starts the sentence.

Comment: I think in English it would read: "Find a "list" of all solutions (x, y, z)", or maybe more simple: "List all solutions (x, y, z)". Or maybe read the translation of "Gesucht ist" as "The solution should be".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*gesucht* is the past participle ("Partizip II") of *suchen*. It is the same construction as in english *wanted*, *needed*, or *appreciated* in the following sentences.

> I am wanted dead or alive.
> With this tool, no further devices are needed.
> Your coöperation is very much appreciated.

It is indicating passive voice here. Your example sentence is present tense (because *ist* is in present tense).

In the concrete example of *gesucht*, it means "sought" or "looked for". It would not be idiomatic to use this participle in English, so one would rather say:

> Wanted is a list of all solutions (x, y, z).

to express the meaning of the German sentence in English.

Answer (score 5):

You may be confused by the fact, that the verb is placed early in the sentence; the meaning would be quite similar in this phrase:

> Eine Liste aller Lösungen wird gesucht

just the emphasis would shift away from the verb.

So I recognize just a verb used in passive construction, but nothing noun-like; this would also be possible, however:

> Das Gesuchte ist eine Liste aller Lösungen.

Comment: I know we're on german.stackexchange so I shouldn't be too surprised if too many commas are used : I don't think there should be one after "by the fact". ;)

Comment: Nitpick: It's "ist gesucht" in the OP, not "wird gesucht".

Answer (score 1):

> functioning as **noun** in a German sentence

This is definitely not the case here.

**Part 1**

In the sentence:

> Die Liste ist sehr lang.

... the expression "sehr lang" definitely is an adjective (with an additional adverb) and not a noun.

In German language, there is the rule of thumb (applying to maybe 90% of all sentences) that you can exchange the order of the parts of a sentence as long as the verb is in the second position.

For this reason, you can place the adjective in front of the sentence:

> Sehr lang ist die Liste.

... if you want to emphasize this part of the sentence.

**Part 2**

The two participles of a verb (in the case of "*suchen*": "*suchend*" and "*gesucht*") are often used like (or as?) adjectives (and **not** as **nouns**) in German language.

Examples:

> Die gesuchte Lösung
>
> Der suchende Student
>
> Der suchende Student sucht die gesuchte Lösung.

**By combining part 1 and part 2** ...

... we can form sentences like the one in your example:

> Gesucht ist die Liste.

However, in such sentences "the verb functions as **adjective**" (this is how you would call it), not as **noun**.

**By the way**

In German language, adjectives may serve as nouns:

> Der Große ist Herr Müller.

... and because the participles of verbs can be used like adjectives, verbs can also be used like nouns:

> Der Suchende ist Herr Müller.

However:

> Gesucht ist die Liste. => "Gesucht" works like an adjective.
>
> Das Gesuchte ist die Liste. => "Das Gesuchte" works like a noun.